# Laravel Validation with vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-resource

i want to post ajax request using vue-resource `this.$http.post` request. it worked perfectly fine if i passed all validation rules but i want to get some validations if it fails. so far i keep getting 500 error if i don't fill out some input fields. it's hard for me to debug the error because it didn't appeared on the network tab.

here's what i've done so far

```
//my modal component
<script>
export default {
    props: ['show'],

    data() {
        return {
            input: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                address: '',
                email: ''
            },
            errorInputs: {}
        }
    },

    methods: {
        createStudent() {
            this.$http.post('/students', this.$data.input)
                .then((response) => {
               alert('added new row!)
            }, (response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
        }
      }
   }
</script>

// my controller

public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->validate($request,[
        'id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|unique:students',
        'email' => 'required|unique:students|email',
        'address' => 'required',
    ]);

    if($validator->passes()){
        Student::create($request->all());

        return response()->json([], 201);
    }

    $errors = json_decode($validator->errors());

    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $errors
    ],422);
}
```

any helps and references would be appreciated. i am using laravel 5.3 and vue js 2

Comment: Maybe you have filters enabled on your network tab? Check if it's `all` (or `xhr` at least) marked on your tab. It'll help for sure. You can also check for logs in `storage/log/laravel.log`

Comment: yeah i realize that after posting my question, sorry. could you help me how to pass laravel validation into vue js component? i am stucked at this point.

Comment: What's the problem then? So far you're heading in good direction as far as I can see

Comment: i can't pass laravel validations data to vue component when validation fails. i want to display them in my template. i know laravel will send json response for ajax request but i can't get those data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->validate()` returns `422` error response alongside your validation errors, so you should get those errors in `then()` second callback (like you do now). Your vue component body should be like this:

```
{
    data() {
        // ...
    },
    createStudent() {
        this.$http
            .post('/students', this.input)
            .then(this.handleSuccess, this.handleError)
    },
    handleSuccess(res) {
        alert('student created')
    },
    handleError(res) {
        if (res.status === 422) {
            this.errorInputs = res.body
        } else {
            alert('Unkown error!')
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to add `v-model="input.fieldName"` properties to your inputs.

Comment: thank you but i still get 500 somehow. there's something wrong on my laravel code i think. i'll comeback to you later

Comment: apparently i have changed render function on `handler.php` to throw exception before this code `return parent::render($request, $exception);`. that's why I keep getting 500 error. validation in vue side works properly now

Comment: @ishadif Geat to hear that! Hopefully my answer helped you at least a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include your session token along with your post, unless of course you are disabling csrf tokens for that route.

Since Laravel 5.1 you can disable this in your verifytoken middleware

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as ...

class VerifyCsrfToken extends ...    {
  protected $except = [
    'payment/*',
  ];
}
```